# Center unknown (responsive) number of images that are floated

Tags: css

I am creating a list of employees, with their photos in a grid format (5 wide). As the number of employees fluctuates I need to be able to center floated elements that don't fill a whole row, without using a containing div for each row. I really feel like it's unlikely I'm the first to want to do this and is struggling, but every solution I've found is to create a container, or some suggest the `inline-block` solution, however these images need to be flush, and as they are `% width` on some browsers some space can be visible between them, even with the `margin-right: -4px` solution; this is why I am depending on floats. Thanks!

What I have

http://pasteboard.co/1u9iCIRy.jpg

What I want

http://pasteboard.co/1u9lKgCh.jpg

Comment: If you don't want the space between them, simply give their parent container `font-size: 0;` while using `inline-block` for the  images.

Comment: We will need to know your code to answer with any accuracy.

Comment: @connexo oh man, you're right! I thought it was `font-size` in the actual element, not the parent.. what is the etiquette here for stupid questions that are answered? Do i request it to be deleted or ask you to actually answer so i can mark it right?

Comment: actually, never mind, already been down voted, might as well leave it there for all the critics to go to town on.

Comment: Put it as an answer including working sample code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want the space between them, simply give their parent container `font-size: 0; text-align: center;` while using `inline-block` for the images.

```css
.imagecontainer {
  font-size: 0;
  text-align: center;
}

.imagecontainer img {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="imagecontainer">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/200x300" alt="" /> 
  <img src="http://placehold.it/200x300" alt="" /> 
  <img src="http://placehold.it/200x300" alt="" /> 
  <img src="http://placehold.it/200x300" alt="" /> 
  <img src="http://placehold.it/200x300" alt="" /> 
  <img src="http://placehold.it/200x300" alt="" /> 
  <img src="http://placehold.it/200x300" alt="" /> 
  <img src="http://placehold.it/200x300" alt="" /> 
  <img src="http://placehold.it/200x300" alt="" /> 
  <img src="http://placehold.it/200x300" alt="" /> 
  <img src="http://placehold.it/200x300" alt="" /> 
  <img src="http://placehold.it/200x300" alt="" /> 
  <img src="http://placehold.it/200x300" alt="" /> 
  <img src="http://placehold.it/200x300" alt="" /> 
  <img src="http://placehold.it/200x300" alt="" /> 
  <img src="http://placehold.it/200x300" alt="" /> 
  <img src="http://placehold.it/200x300" alt="" /> 
  <img src="http://placehold.it/200x300" alt="" /> 
  <img src="http://placehold.it/200x300" alt="" /> 
  <img src="http://placehold.it/200x300" alt="" /> 
</div>
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LZpGbZ

Answer (score 0):

You could use [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) and `justify-content: center`. And a fixed `width` of the flex container.

Here is a proof of concept for a fixed 5-column layout: http://jsbin.com/hegogigiyo/1/edit?html,css,output.

You can see the layout of 10 images, 11 images ... 15 images.